# $f(x)=3x-7$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=3x-7$ is not bounded.

---

The definition of an unbounded function is given by:
$$
\forall M>0, \exists x\in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } |f(x)|\geq M
$$

---

**This is what I have so far:**

Let $M>0$ and $|3x-7|\geq M$

Separated them into 2 cases ($x<\frac{7}{3}$) and ($x\geq\frac{7}{3}$)

And I found out that I can pick $x\leq -\frac{M-7}{3}$ and $x\geq \frac{M+7}{3}$

So how do I pick a value of x for my formal proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this by contradiction.
For every positive $M$, let $x=\frac{M+10}{3}$, then
$$f(x)=3x-7$$
$$=3\left(\frac{M+10}{3}\right)-7$$
$$=M+10-7=M+3>M$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, the concept of *bounded* means that the function is always above or below a certain value. In your case, it is much simpler to split the proof into two distinct cases of $f$ being bounded above and bounded below.

Assume (for the sake of contradiction) that $f$ is bounded below. Then, there exists some $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $M < f(x)$ for all real $x$. Then we have $M < 3x-7$, which is equivalent to $x > (M+7)/3$. So, picking any $x < (M+7/3)$ would yield $f(x) < M$, which is a contradition.

Now assume $f$ is bounded above. Could you complete the proof?

Comment: What do you mean by bounded below/above?

Comment: No worries, I get it

Comment: @MengenLiu A function is bounded above if it never exceeds a fixed value, and it is bounded below if a certain value never exceeds it.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your life noticing that $3x-7>x$ for $x\ge 4$

(indeed $x\ge 4\implies (3x-7)-x=(2x-7)\ge 8-7=1>0$).

And you just need to take $x=\max(4,M)$